# Insert value referencing another field

Tags: hsqldb

After creating a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    C1 INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    C2 INTEGER);
```

I would like to insert in C2 the same value of C1:

```
INSERT INTO T1(C1, C2) VALUES (DEFAULT, C1)
```

I could only do something that resembles this by introducing a sequence, is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the C2 value is not going to be changed, you can declare it as a GENERATED column.

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
C1 INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) PRIMARY KEY,
C2 INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (C1));
```

Inserts are done with DEFAULT values.

```
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES DEFAULT, DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for this, as at the time the insert is happening, the auto generated value might not even be available yet.  But, one workaround at the data layer which you could use might be to just insert `NULL` values into `C2` whenever you want them to just reflect the value in `C1`.  That is, use this insert for these cases:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (C2)
VALUES (NULL);
```

Then, when you select, use `COALESCE` to report the `C1` value for `C2`:

```
SELECT C1, COALESCE(C2, C1) AS C2
FROM T1;
```